# 1D cluster - Jenks optimization - Finding optimal number

Tags: machine-learning, python, clustering, optimization, timeseries-segmentation

I have a sample data variable shown below

```
score
10,
11,
12,
90,
95,
97,
38,
37,
35
```

Instead of applying/binning data based on `quantiles` etc, I would like to bin based on pattern present in the data.

That's when I came to know about the `jenks natural breaks` [here](https://pbpython.com/natural-breaks.html)

However, this approach requires us to define the `n_clusters` for us to segment the data

This is what I tried as of now

```
df['score_segment'] = pd.cut(
    df['score'],
    bins=jenkspy.jenks_breaks(df['score'], nb_class=5),
    labels=[1,2,3,4,5],
    include_lowest=True)
```

Is there any automated approach that can give us the optimal number of clusters for 1D data based on its property?

Comment: "Optimal" in what sense?  This is a particularly apt issue because typically Jenks' method is used to establish a discrete scale for mapping data, whence "optimal" would ordinarily mean in terms of what message you want a map to convey.

Comment: @whuber - By optimal, I mean, I would like to know the optimal number of clusters. How should we define the no of clusters?

Comment: That's not a criterion. "Optimal" means *best* in some sense: to know the optimal number of clusters, you need to specify a way to determine when one number is better or worse than another.

Comment: @whuber - sorry for delayed response. I would like to optimize GVF (Goodness of Variance Fit) to determine n_classes. May I seek your help with this related post where I have questions on interpretation and optimization?https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/589557/jenks-natural-breaks-interpreting-goodness-of-variance-fit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a two stage problem: first, identify the number of clusters and then, secondly, optimally perform the clustering.

For the first part, I'd suggest [Cluster Validation by Prediction Strength](https://towardsdatascience.com/prediction-strength-a-simple-yet-relatively-unknown-way-to-evaluate-clustering-2e5eaf56643) to identify the number of clusters. The linked article has Python code and links to a github with R code to perform this.

Once you've identified the number of clusters, you could use the R package [Ckmeans.1d.dp](https://rdrr.io/cran/Ckmeans.1d.dp/) to do the optimal 1 dimensional clustering.