# Jenks Natural breaks - Interpreting Goodness of Variance Fit

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, clustering, data-mining, k-means

I am trying to find breaks in a multiple continuous type variables.

So, I tried the `jenks natural breaks algorithm`.

Based on the code from [here](https://github.com/gianfelton/RFM-Segmentation-with-Quartiles-Jenks-Natural-Breaks-and-HDBSCAN/blob/master/RFM%20Segmentation.ipynb), I managed to find the `goodness of variance fit` (GVF) for each of my variables.

I understand GVF closer to 1 is a good fit and closer to 0 is bad fit.

But now, looking at the below graphs, how do I select the number of classes?

All of them seem to have good score at n_classes = 9 but I see that after n_classes=5 there is no much improvement.

So, should I stick to n_classes = 5?

Is it purely a business decision and tradeoff between n_classes and GVF score?

**Or how can I know that n_classes = 5 is better than n_classes = 4 or n_classes = 9? How do we assess/judge whether my decision to choose n_classes = 5 is better than n_classes=4?**

**What does a value of 90% for GVF mean? Does it mean, 90% of the data for that group is well-separated from other groups?**

Can I seek your inputs on this?

[image]

Comment: If you have to worry whether you have identified natural breaks, those breaks aren't natural.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Slocum (2009), when the curve is becoming flat, there is no improvement, so you can select between 4 and 6 based on your graphs.

Five classes may be a good number but it depends on what you want, if you prefer as many as possible or the contrary. For example, in a map, this is used to assign a set of colors and in order to get the maximum difference among them, sometimes it is better to use fewer classes, but in that case, the resolution of the classification is lower because there are fewer classes.

The algorithm helps, but the final decision is yours.

You can know that 5 or 4 classes,... are better, by reviewing the value for GVF on each variable.

Yes, a value next to 1 means there are clusters in your data (groups of similar values that are well separated from other groups, also with similar values).

Comment: Please provide full details to Slocum (2009).